# Perl: Proper way to call a symbolic subref to a module's subroutine?

Tags: perl

Assume you have a module (eg *Foo.pm*) with *package Foo*.  Inside it exists many subroutine definitions, including ones for *foo* and *default*.

```
package Foo;
sub foo     { ... }
sub default { ... }
```

Inside your main perl program (eg *test.pl*) what is the proper way to assign a value to a subref and call it, or otherwise call default?

```
sub call_proc {
   my $args   = shift;
   my $subref = $args->{proc_name} // 'default';

   &$Foo::subref();                               # <====== Wrong
}
call_proc({ proc_name => q{foo} });               # make the call
```

Comment: Is the module/script that defines `call_proc` also calling `use Foo`?

Comment: @mob: good question - no.  edited the question

Comment: I'm using a dispatch table elsewhere, but it seems trivial to create one for each and every function to ease abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\&$name` isn't caught by strict refs, so:

```
sub call_proc {
   my $args     = shift;
   my $sub_name = $args->{proc_name} // 'default';
   my $sub_ref  = \&{ "Foo::" . $sub_name };
   #die if !defined(&$sub_ref);
   return $sub_ref->();
}
```

If we're talking about methods, then it would be:

```
sub call_method {
   my $args        = shift;
   my $method_name = $args->{method_name} // 'default';
   #die if !Foo->can($method_name);
   return Foo->$method_name();
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have to check it out later

Comment: beautiful. I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this with `UNIVERSAL::can`:

```
sub call_proc {
   my $args   = shift;
   my $subref = Foo->can($args->{proc_name}) // 'default';

   if ($subref) {
       &$subref();
   }
}
call_proc({ proc_name => q{foo} });
```

Comment: I just looked at the `UNIVERSAL::can` source, it looks like they're just wrapping it in an eval.  Is that right?

Comment: `can` checks inheritance. It should only be used for methods, not procs.

Comment: can worked, but after doing some reading like you said, it should be used for methods to check the existence of a class method - I think.  In in this case the module is more similar to Brian D'Foy's modulino, with a bunch of independent subroutines.

Comment: This would have been my accepted answer, since it worked, but I think ikegami's is what I was after

Answer (score 1):

If `$subref` is `some_method_name`, then `&$subref` (or `$subref->()`) will try to call a function called `some_method_name` *in the current package*. Depending on how your program is set up, you may want to pass a fully qualified subroutine name

```
call_proc( { proc_name => 'Foo::foo' });
```

or put some logic into `call_proc` to qualify it. See the `qualify_sub_name` function in [`Forks::Super::Util`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MOB/Forks-Super-0.63/lib/Forks/Super/Util.pm) for an idea about how to do this.

You can also safely use a reference to the function

```
call_proc( { proc_name => \&foo } );   # works if &foo is avail in current pkg
```

Comment: yes, [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlref.html) and [other documentation](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/advprog/ch04_01.htm) has plenty of examples for internal references, but that little package qualifier is making this difficult.  I'll try your example and append the package during the assignment.

Comment: ***Update:*** I tried it out and I keep getting `Can't use string ("Foo::default") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use...`

Comment: Yeah, there is that `strict` thing. Then you either need to use code references or wrap the function call in `no strict 'refs'`.